# Не работает Ruby 2.1 и выше на Windows XP

Tags: windows, ruby, windows-xp

При попытке запустить `irb` или `.rb` файлы на Ruby 2.1 и выше появляется ошибка:

> Приложение завершено из-за нажатия сочетания клавиш CTRL+C

*Ruby 2.0 p648* и ниже работают нормально.

Как запустить руби последних версий на XP? Как вариант пробовал Jruby, но версия выше *9.1.17.0* не работает, да и ждать по 10 сек. пока запустится .rb файл не вариант.

Установлена Windows XP SP3 Professional с последними обновами.

Comment: Как вариант, уйти с древней системы на что-то посвежее?

Comment: Это само собой. Но меня интересует запуск именно на XP.